# How to find number of observation between first observation and observation with maximal value

Tags: r

I have a large data frame and I need a function to automate this search. Basically I want to find how many observations are between the first observation and the observation with maximal value.

Example:

```r
x <- c(2, 1, 9, 3, 4, -6, 5, 11, 6, -7, -1)
```

Assuming that this is my data I want to count the number of data points between 2 and 11.

I need to do this in r.

Help is highly appreciated :D !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can eithe

```
diff(which(x %in% c(2, max(x)))) -1
#[1] 6
```

Or substract the index of the max value (`which.max`) from the first value (+1 - not including the elements)

```
which.max(x) - x[1]
```

Comment: I need to automate this. What if I use ```diff(which(x %in% c(2,max(x)))```

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"diff(which(x %in% c(2,max(x)))
diff"

Comment: @TigranDanielyan can you try again as I couldn't reproudce that error

Comment: I have used ```which.max(n) - n[1]-1``` and it works thanks!

Comment: @TigranDanielyan i was thinking that difference is from the max and 1 and not first value